# How can I change the size of the decimal part of a number?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to print a decimal number inside a textview with a special format: the part on the left of the comma in one particular size and the part on the right in a different size.

Any idea about how can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make use of `SpannableString`

```
  TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        String value = "10.3";
        final SpannableString text = new SpannableString(value);
        text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), value.indexOf(".")+1, value.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), value.indexOf(".")+1, value.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        tv.setText(text);
```

for more refer these
http://alexandroid.net/spannablestring-example/
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html
https://takeoffandroid.com/android-spannable-text-view-to-change-color-size-style-and-adding-click-event-for-particular-word-8acd8a05ec61

Answer (score 0):

Use SpannableString..

**Example**

```
String yourText = "20.00";
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(yourText);
ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), youString.indexOf(".") + 1, youString.length(), 0);
yourTextview.setText(ss);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example doing this

```
double number = 422.343;

String completeNumber = String.valueOf(number);

int decimalPointIndex = completeNumber.indexOf('.');

SpannableString ss=  new SpannableString(completeNumber);
ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0,decimalPointIndex, 0);

textView.setText(ss);
```

1. Convert the decimal number to String
2. Get index value of decimal point
3. Then use it and display the first part before decimal as bigger